# Can the Task Factory REST Source for SSIS do NTLM authentication?

Tags: authentication, ssis

Documentation only shows basic user/pass and OAuth setups. Does anyone know if the Task Factory REST connection managers can use Windows Auth (NTLM), and if so, point me to an example or documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. SentryOne support responded with the answer "no, it's not supported."